# log user IP address per api call or per session

Tags: authentication, ip

I need to store the IP address of the user for further analysis of IP location and other security investigation.
I am creating session tokens with a 20 minutes expiration - is it sufficient to store only the IP address when the client tries to renew his session token or should I log it on every call? The issue being the log storage space...

Thanks,

Comment: You should be logging everything if this is for security audits. Log space should not be a limitation.

Comment: like what Trickycm said, take a look at the access logs from Apache or Nginx ... when in doubt log all the things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're simply trying to grab the IP for analysis of location, then you only need that once.  Grabbing the IP multiple time, per connection will not add more information to aid in an investigation unless you're expecting the target user's IP to renew at every connection.

If you are concerned about the level of information then you may want to consider grabbing the MAC, username and or system name, if possible, in your setup.  All of these can easily be spoofed and changed, but it may provide more valuable information in the case that a target user IP is coming from a NAT'd public IP.